# why is my 4year old weeping willow getting yellow tips ?

Tags: weeping-willow

my 4 year old weeping willow developed brown/yellow leaves on its tips.  They touch the ground, is the fungicide for the lawn a possibility?  it started out looking great this year

Comment: Could we get pictures, please? And don’t forget to take the [tour] and browse our [help]. Welcome to Gardening SE!

Comment: Why did you apply fungicide to your lawn?  Simply the leaves touching the ground will get bruised and damaged just with a little breeze.  I always cut the leaves up from the ground a few feet or whatever.  Are the tips of the leaves only the leaves touching the ground?  Fungicide kills fungus not herbaceous material, normally.  Did you use weed killer in your fertilizers or spray weed killer on your lawn?  Now that would cause a few problems, not enough to kill your tree.  Fungicides, herbicides, moss killer, pesticides do not need to be used for maintenance, at all.